# Input image does not match with signature file in supervised classification

Tags: arcmap, remote-sensing, classification, erdas-imagine, image-classification

I have a issue in supervised classification on ERDAS IMAGINE. When ever I performed supervised classification it gives a warning message. It says:

> iInput image does not match signature's image association.

I don't know why this message is given and output image is completely a single color.

Comment: Could you please highlight the precise steps you took to perform the classification including a description of your imagery?

Comment: First I have created a signature file, which has only crop signature. Then I opened supervised classification tool and select the input image, from where I have created the signature file. Then I selected the signature file. Give a output location. In Non parametric rule option I have chosen Non-option and in parametric rule option I have chosen Maximum likelihood. Classify zero and Use probability are both unchecked. Then I select Ok option.